One Sided Limits with Natural Log, Substitution for input
$$\lim_{a \to 0^{-}}(\ln(\left| a \right|)) = \lim_{a \to 0^{-}}(\ln(-a)) = \lim_{a \to 0^{-}}(\ln(t)) = \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}(\ln(t)) = -\infty $$
from steps 2, 3 and 4 we substitue t for -a, and the approaches part of the limit changes, the logic given by photomath is since a approaches 0 from negative side and t = -a, then t apporoaches 0 from the positive side, what can the reasoning behind this be? Thanks. This problem is actually part of a improper integral problem $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1}{x}dx$ but i just need to know the initial idea.

The first way to explain it is the calculus way. When we are looking at $\lim_{a \to 0^-}{f(a)}$, we are looking at what happens to $f(a)$ as we take values of $a$ from the left of $0$ which get closer and closer to $0$. I.e we are looking at negative $a$ getting closer and closer to $0$. So imagine we take $a=-1$, then $a=-0.5, -0.25, \dots$ and at each of these $a$ we look at what $f(a)$ is.
When we make the substitution $t = -a$, we start with the same points $a = -1, -0.5, \dots$ and then say what does $t = -a$ look like. Well $t = - (-1), - (-0.5), \dots = 1, 0.5, \dots$. So we are now looking at positive values but still getting closer to $0$, i.e $t \to 0^+$
For your interest, the more rigorous, analysis approach begins with the definition of a left sided limit. For $\lim_{a \to 0^-}{f(a)} = L$, we have for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f(0) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad a \in (-\infty, 0) \quad \text{with} \quad  0-a = -a < \delta$$
Then making the substitution $t=-a$, we have
$$|f(0) - L| < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad a \in (0, \infty) \quad \text{with} \quad t = t-0 < \delta$$
Which one can see is very similar to the left sided limit defintion, but the $t$ and $0$ are flipped. And indeed this is the right sided limit definition. So in other words, $\lim_{t \to 0^+}{f(a)}$

Thank you @jacobwalker, in a way your describing how the substitution worked in my original idea and with your answer in the context of how your defined the left sided limit  (which applies the substition to make it the right sided limit definition or idea).

@Kcharliee No problem. I would also like to add, as Yves mentioned in the comments, your third step can be confusing. I wouldn't call it wrong, but mixing two variables from a subsitution you made can be confusing. It's better just to substitute every instance of the variable straight away (unless there is a specific reason/use in keeping part of the expression in terms of the original variable).

tbh, it was photomaths logic or approach, this whole limit thing was a part of a improper integral problem if you look at my question.

@Kcharliee Yeah, that is fair. I just thought I'd clear up what I think Yves comment was aiming to address, since he didn't.
